# jquery bxslider : how to add controls button prev next with ticker mode

Tags: jquery, bxslider, ticker

I add bxslider with ticker mode on a website.

```
$('.slider1').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideMargin: 10,
    ticker: true,
    speed: 70000
});
```

It's works fine but i want to add controls "next/prev" and i fail !

I try to add options :

```
controls : true
pager : true
```

I also try to add custom controls :

```
nextSelector: '#slider-next',
prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
nextText: 'Onward →',
prevText: '← Go back',
```

I didn't find any solution in the docs.

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you